# How to access Many-to-Many relationship from different related models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
class Instrument(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

class Instrumentation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    instrument = models.ManyToManyField('Instrument', through='InstrumentMap')

class InstrumentMap(models.Model):
    instrumentation = models.ForeignKey(Instrumentation, verbose_name=_('instrumentation'), related_name='instrumentmap', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    instrument = models.ForeignKey(Instrument, verbose_name=_('instrument'), related_name='instrumentmap', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    numbers = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class Work_Music(MPTTModel, Work):
    instrumentation = models.ForeignKey(Instrumentation, verbose_name=_('instrumentation'), related_name='work', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

1. How do I get access to all the instruments under an instrumentation object from work?

For example:

```
piece = Work_Music.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

I tried `piece.instrumentation_set.all`. That didn't work?

2. How do you get access from instrumentation?

`instrumentation = Instrumentation.objects.get(instrumentation__work=self.kwargs['pk'])`

I guess you do a `for` loop when you can grab the object.

3. How do you get access from instrumentmap?

`InstrumentMap = InstrumentMap.objects.filter(instrumentation__work=self.kwargs['pk']).order_by('order')`

Answer (score 2):

1. Instrumentation is a foreign key, so you must use:

   ```
   piece = Work_Music.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
   piece.instrumentation.instrumentmap.all()
   ```
2. You can use reverse many_to_one relation:

   ```
   instrumentation = Instrumentation.objects.get(work__id=self.kwargs['pk'])
   ```
3. You can access with:

   ```
   instrument_maps = InstrumentMap.objects.filter(instrumentation__work__id=self.kwargs['pk'])
   ```